# ASP.NET Core weird URL parsing. Single query string parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, url-routing

I want to pass a string parameter to an action. Acreated a method in the `HomeController` with the following signature:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult TestView([FromQuery] string test)
{
    return View(test);
}
```

This is my configuration class:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

When I go to https://localhost:5001/Home/TestView it works ok
When I add a query string ?test=myvalue it fails to find the view. It tries to locate the view using weird paths.

```
    InvalidOperationException: The view 'myvalue' was not found. The following locations were searched:
    /Views/Home/myvalue.cshtml
    /Views/Shared/myvalue.cshtml
```

Is that a bug?

Comment: what's your middlewares in Startup.cs?

Comment: @Jacek I posted the whole Startup.cs. Though, I haven't touched it. It's from default MVC templete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is occurring because you passed the value "myvalue" as the first parameter of your returned ViewResult, which is the viewname parameter:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewresult.viewname?view=aspnetcore-5.0

If you change your return statement to:

```
return View();
```

Then you won't be passing a view name parameter and it will then search for a view named TestView.

Comment: No worries bro. If you were expecting to see "myvalue" in the browser, change your return type to string and then can return test, bypassing views altogether. Or you could instead bind the value to the view. Just depends what you want to do.

Comment: @SergеуIsupov the first argument is the view name, if you want to pass something to the view, pass it to the second argument. So in your case, you can write `View("TestView", test)` - the view model then is of type `string` which should be aware of by the view to use it correctly.